# CSS: position element outside of area without changing scrollbar

Tags: html, css, typeahead.js

I have a modal dialog which has a vertical scrollbar that appears when the modal contents are too large to be contained.

My problem is: when a control (actually a Twitter Typeahead https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) that I want to "popout" of the modal appears, it causes the scrollbar on the modal to extend.

Probably best explained by example:

**Desired behaviour**

https://jsfiddle.net/0eara5xc/14/ shows the behaviour I want (enter the letter 'a' in the input box), however the modal does not scroll when the regular content is too large (which I need).

**Undesired behaviour**

As soon as I make the modal scrollable, the popup causes the scrollbar to increase.

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: 40vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0eara5xc/13/ (scroll down and enter the letter 'a' in the input box)
I actually want the popup to flow outside of the modal as per the first example.

The Twitter Typeahead control creates its own position:relative and position:absolute elements, so I don't think I can use CSS to absolutely position the dynamically created popup elements.

Comment: Probably you can provide a fiddle with a typeahead?

Comment: Fiddles updated

Comment: I suggest you take out the input field out of the scrollable area of the modal if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you want to have 2 things that are contradictory. I am going to explain with few examples until I reach my idea of solution.

If we take in-flow elements (a container and an inner element) we have two situtaion:

(1)  The height of the inner element **is smaller or equal** to the height of the container. In this case all the overflow (`auto`, `scroll` and `hidden`) are the same.

(2) The height of the inner element **is bigger** than the height of container and in this case we:

- Keep the default behavior and we will have an **overflow** and we can **see** the element **outside**.

```css
.el {
  border:5px solid green;
  height:100px;
}
.el > div {
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">
   <div>
   
   </div>
 </div>
```

- Use `overflow:hidden` to hide some of the inner element so we **cannot see** the overflowing part.

```css
.el {
  border:5px solid green;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.el > div {
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">
   <div>
   
   </div>
 </div>
```

- Use `overflow:scroll` to hide some of the inner element and we **can only see** the overflowing part **on scroll**.

```css
.el {
  border:5px solid green;
  height:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
.el > div {
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">
   <div>
   
   </div>
 </div>
```

So technically we cannot have the element overflowing with a scroll.

---

When using `absolute:position` we will be in the situation (2) almost in all the case (unless we define a big height for the container) because absolute positioned element is out of the flow and is **not considered in the height calculation of the container** so logically the height of inner elements will be bigger and the same logic above will apply:

```css
.el {
  border:5px solid green;
  position:relative;
}
.el > div {
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
.el > div:last-child {
  position:absolute;
  background:blue;
  right:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">
   <div>
     we see the element
   </div>
   <div>
   
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="el" style="overflow:hidden;margin-top:100px;">
   <div>
      we don't see the element
   </div>
   <div>
   
   </div>
 </div>
 
  <div class="el" style="overflow:scroll;">
   <div>
      we see the element element on scroll
   </div>
   <div>
   
   </div>
 </div>
```

The same logic also apply even if the `overflow` property is set to another element ancestor of the absolute positioned element. As you can read [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/):

> In most cases, overflow can be computed for any box from the bounds
>   and properties of that box itself, **plus the overflow of each of its**
>   **children.**

So using `overflow:scroll` will always make the scroll to increase when any child element is increasing in height or is having overflow AND there is no way to have any overflowing element outside since this is the default behavior and you change it by setting `overflow:scroll`.

### **The solution**

The first easy solution to avoid the scroll to be applied to your element is to make the element positioned relative to an ancestor of the element on where you applied the scroll. In other words: between the element with `overflow:scroll` and the absolute postioned element you should not find any positioned element. As you can read in this *complex* statement [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow-clipping):

> ... a box may overflow, meaning its content lies partly or entirely
>   outside of the box, e.g.:
>
> [...]
>
> A descendant box is positioned absolutely, partly outside the box.
>   Such boxes are not always clipped by the overflow property on their
>   ancestors; specifically, they are not clipped by the overflow of any
>   ancestor between themselves and their containing block

This solution will of course break your code.

---

The other idea is to make the element `position:fixed`. Like this it will be relative to browser window and we can see it outside the scroll BUT it will be difficult to adjust its position using CSS. In this case we can consider some JS to dynamically adjust the position of the element:

```
$('.typeahead').on('keypress change',function(e){
  var y = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
  var x = $(this).offset().left;
  $('.tt-menu').css('top',y);
  $('.tt-menu').css('left',x);
})
```

As you can see, we simply calculate the top/left position of the element based on the position of the input.

Here is the full code:

```js
$(function () {
$('.typeahead').on('keypress change',function(e){
  var y = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()+5;
  var x = $(this).offset().left;
  $('.tt-menu').css('top',y);
  $('.tt-menu').css('left',x);
})



  $('#btnPopup').on('click', function(){
   $('#divPopup').toggle();
  });
  
  var substringMatcher = function(strs) {

  return function findMatches(q, cb) {

    var matches, substringRegex;



    // an array that will be populated with substring matches

    matches = [];



    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`

    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');



    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that

    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array

    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {

      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {

        matches.push(str);

      }

    });



    cb(matches);

  };

};



var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',

  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',

  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',

  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',

  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',

  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',

  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',

  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',

  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'

];



$('.typeahead').typeahead({

  hint: true,

  highlight: true,

  minLength: 1

},

{

  name: 'states',

  source: substringMatcher(states)

});
  
});
```

```css
.modal-body {
  
 max-height: 40vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-header, .modal-footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#divSpacer {
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

.tt-menu {
  background-color: red;
  position:fixed!important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-header">
      My modal title
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div id="divSpacer">
        Lots of space taken up here...
      </div>
      
       <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
      
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspected that a pure CSS solution was not possible, and you have convinced me. I might try a variation on your second solution.  I will move the element into the parent of the scrollable div and position it absolutely, which will require calculating the position relative to the parent element instead of the browser window.  I will have to listen to the scroll event of the scrollable area and reposition it too.

Answer (score 1):

Update your fiddle with:

```
.tt-menu {
  background-color: red;
  top:auto !important;
  bottom:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zd4xf0oo/

Comment: I need the solution to be generic.  When the modal is not large enough, the "drop up" menu doesn't display properly and an unnecessary scroll bar is shown.  https://jsfiddle.net/zd4xf0oo/2/

Comment: If the modal is not large enough the menu will cause the scrollbar anyway. Also if you need a **generic** solution, you have to write some JS to check the modal's height and apply the corresponding styles.

Comment: "If the modal is not large enough the menu will cause the scrollbar anyway"  That's the point :)  I don't want it to cause the scrollbar.  I want it to appear outside of the modal.  I only want the scrollbar when the actual modal content (excluding the typeahead popup) requires it.  I could probably do some hacky javascript to move the popup element outside of the modal div and then reposition it,  but I'd really like to avoid that at all costs.

Comment: This is a problem where generic solution is "I don't think so" type. Overflow auto means it will definitely show the scrollbar when suggestions popup as the input is the bottom-most element, unless you bring it outside by JS or fix it with absolute/fixed positioning when you have to position it on event of scroll or window resize. I like the idea of showing the suggestions above the input box. In case you have little content like the JSFiddle you commented, just put your content inside a div which has min-height 200px, sounds like __GENERIC SOLUTION__ to me.

Comment: @MunimMunna Well, it's generic, but I wouldn't consider it a solution.  Having a mandatory whitespace above or below every typeahead control would look extremely bad, especially since the control could appear anywhere in a list of form controls.